# Suppress mouse scroll events on specific controls but NOT their parent?

Tags: delphi, scroll, combobox, mousewheel

I have a form which is embedded inside of a scroll box. I implement scrolling in the scroll box like so:

```
procedure TfrmPO.sbItemsMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  sbItems.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_PAGEDOWN, 0);
end;

procedure TfrmPO.sbItemsMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  sbItems.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_PAGEUP, 0);
end;
```

This does the trick just fine, however there are also a number of combo box controls within this form. If the focus is within one of these, it will also scroll the items within that combo box. So I need to disable such effects.

I have tried two solutions which do in fact work, however both solutions also introduce a new issue: the parent scroll box never receives the messages and thus does not scroll as desired. If the focus is in another control, the parent does scroll, but if the focus is in a combo box, nothing scrolls.

**Attempt 1:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Screen.ActiveControl is TComboBox then Handled := True;
end;
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
type
  TComboBox = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox)
  protected
    function DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; override;
  end;

.....

{ TComboBox }

function TComboBox.DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
  MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  Result:= True;
end;
```

How can I disable the mouse wheel scrolling in specific controls without disabling it on its parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mouse wheel messages are propagated to the parent chain of the control which receive them, until it is *handled*. So set `Handled` to true where you actually handle them, in the scrollbox. Do not put any message handler anywhere else, so that the message is sent to the parent.

```
procedure TfrmPO.sbItemsMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := True;
  sbItems.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_PAGEDOWN, 0);
end;
```

Comment: I'm assuming the actual scrolling action is not performed until after the propagation has completed, rather than at the moment the message has been received. Correct?

Comment: @Jerry that's correct, the default handler is called only if no one has set handled. You can see in the last line of TControl.WMMouseWheel, Message.Result is 1 if the receiving control, or one in the parent chain *handles* the message.